# Is there any way to detect user finger touch on camera[same functionality of heart rate monitor] & start video capturing?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, heartrate

I want to capture video when the user touches on the camera, on the detection of the user's finger & starts capturing video and saves it in storage.

I have tried https://github.com/kibotu/Heart-Rate-Ometer library but it's not getting success to capture video. Please help.

Thanks..